# Can't move data from a DataTable to a DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, ado.net, datatable

The data reaches the DataTable (11 columns and 3 rows), but when I try to have it reach the DataGridView, no success (no error, just an empty "DataGridView"). Here is the portion of the relevant code:

```
DataGridView SecuritiesGridView1 = new DataGridView();
BindingSource bindingSource1 = new BindingSource();
SecuritiesGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource1;

String connectionString = "Data Source=|DataDirectory|\\PersonalFinanceDB.sdf;Encrypt Database=True;Persist Security Info=True";

SqlCeDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlCeDataAdapter(DBcommand, connectionString);

DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

bindingSource1.DataSource = table;
SecuritiesGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource1;
dataAdapter.Fill(table);

MessageBox.Show("Number of columns of table: " + table.Columns.Count.ToString());  // Returns 11
MessageBox.Show("Number of rows of table: " + table.Rows.Count.ToString());  // Returns 3

MessageBox.Show("Number of rows of grid: " + SecuritiesGridView1.RowCount.ToString());  // Returns 0
MessageBox.Show("Number of columns of grid: " + SecuritiesGridView1.ColumnCount.ToString());  // Returns 0
```

Anybody would have an idea what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: I don't see anything that connects the `BindingSource` to the `DataTable`

Comment: Try moving the `dataAdapter.Fill(table)` before the setting of the `DataSource`?

Comment: Something is still missing from your code sample. If I setup a very similar example but am actually displaying the grid on a form, the data is loaded and displayed correctly. Which is basically how MSDN also describes how to bind a datagridview to a binding source http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fbk67b6z.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of how you fill the table, you need to bind the DataGridView to the DataTable.

Something like:

```
BindingSource myBindingSource = new BindingSource();
myDataGridView.DataSource = myBindingSource;
DataView myDataView = new DataView(myDataTable);
myBindingSource = myDataView;
```

should do the trick.

Then you can filter the data by changing the view, if that's what you want to do, by doing something like:

```
myDataView.RowFilter = (Dessert = 'Ice Cream');
```

or something like that, and the DataGridView will get filtered to that view.

Comment: Winforms binding can be so icky

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a call to `SecuritiesGridView1.DataBind()` after filling the table with data.

Comment: The Winforms DataGridView doesn't have a DataBind method. Were you thinking of ASP.Net?

Answer (score 0):

First fill the datatable "table" then assign the bindingsource to SecuritiesGridView1 and then call then function SecuritiesGridView1.DataBind();

Comment: The Winforms DataGridView doesn't have a DataBind method. Were you thinking of ASP.Net?

Comment: the above code is working perfectly. Check your datatable on runtime and make sure the presence of data in it.